# How can I make a shortcut to the "Recent Apps" dialog?

Tags: app-widgets, home-screen-shortcuts, recents-screen

Do you know if there is any way to create a shortcut or widget on the homescreen to access to the "Recent Apps" list?
Basically, is there any way to access to this list without having to hold the Home button?

Comment: Which launcher do you use ?

Comment: GoLauncher has a 'recent' tab in the apps pane, if that's any help. Not really desktop though

Comment: I use ADW Launcher EX and I actually don't want to change it :/

Comment: Launcher Pro has a swipe gesture that shows recently used apps.

Comment: Related: [How to simulate long press home button?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/21274)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. Just move the icon to your homepage as a shortcut and you're good to go :)

[MoreRecent](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.britoso.morerecent)

[image]

via [droidforums.net](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-x-hacks/118107-recent-apps.html#post1216819)

Comment: Thanks! Well it's not a shortcut to the real Recent Apps dialog but it seems this is the closest thing I will get.

Comment: @Leimi It's not your inbuilt OS Recent Apps dialog but I believe apps can retrieve the list of the latest apps used so therefore the list should be the same but a little longer.

Comment: Yeah the apps are the same but the application style/theme isn't :p

Comment: The link is dead. An update is required to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I made a free widget to do this, you can get it from the Play Store [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.w8ds.recentapps).

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Recent Apps Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.appkicker.app) available on Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

[App Bar Widgets](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.romoapps.widget.recentapps) just what you're looking for.

Comment: The link is dead. An update is required here.

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [Recent Task 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kaija.activityhistory2) on Play Store.