# How to simulate long press home button?

Tags: recents-screen, home-button

I'm running ICS on HTC Desire. Long pressing the home button brings the list of recently opened apps. Is there a way I can launch this without using the home button?

Please note that I want to do what long-pressing home button does, i.e. bring the stock opened app list not any third party one.

Comment: Related: [How can I make a shortcut to the "Recent Apps" dialog?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/5876)

Answer (score 1):

You can open the recent apps list  using [adb](/questions/tagged/adb).

Setup [ADB in PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42474/is-there-a-minimal-installation-of-adb), connect the phone into PC, [enable USB debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707137/how-to-find-and-turn-on-usb-debugging-mode-on-nexus-4) in phone, launch a shell on PC, and enter:

```
adb shell input keyevent --longpress 3
```

`3` is a [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) to call Home. See more of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28969112/4720957). Also, if the recent list isn't bind to long press Home key but to another key like Menu/Overview key then the command wouldn't result in any visible activity on device. In that case, look for the KeyEvent associated to your key.

The parameter `--longpress` [isn't available to Android versions prior to Kitkat release](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27630157/4720957) so the command would give you error on ICS or JB.

Alternatively, in my devices I found that the activity responsible for bringing that list is managed by SystemUI. You can call that activity using ADB to show that recent apps list.

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.systemui/.recent.RecentsActivity
```

(Add `--activity-clear-task` at the end if the activity doesn't show up in front. Space is important before `--`.)

This worked on Android 4.2.1, 4.4.2 and 5.0.2. For Lollipop, use `com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity` to show up recent apps list in 3D, otherwise, you would see a 2D list which is usual for Android 4.x.

As for launching it within the device without entering the commands, simply use [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) or [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) to make home screen shortcuts for the said activity.

Comment: One can consider this answer too : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20537408/4720957